# How to bind individual collection items to different text boxes in WPF

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, binding, .net-4.0, wpf-4.0

Say I have a collection of phone numbers:

```
phonenumbers.add(new phonenumber("mobile", "1234"));
phonenumbers.add(new phonenumber("home", "5678"));
```

If I have 2 text boxes, txtMobile and txtHome, how do I bind each phone number to the individual text boxes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can index your bindings in WPF. Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding phonenumbers[0]}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding phonenumbers[1]}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. My source is actually a LINQ class, Member.PhoneNumbers. Each member can have at most 3 types of phone number types. I want to be able bind each text box to each type of phone number? Something like Text="{Binding Member.PhoneNumbers["Mobile"]}". Is it possible? Any other way of achieving it?

Comment: I *believe* that an indexer can be of any type. Try Text="{Binding Member.PhoneNumbers['Mobile']}"

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I hope you have other suggestions.

Comment: It didn't? Is your PhoneNumbers collection a property on the class rather than a field? Did you remember the single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to indicies.

```
Text={Binding phonenumbers[0]}
```

Otherwise create individual properties for the phone numbers and bind to them.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my comment to Matt Hamilton. I hope you can help me.